# Need help laying out a site with dojo

Tags: zend-framework, dojo, dijit.layout

basically guys i will like to layout a website with dojo where by i will have a header, content area ( this is divided in two with some accordions in the left pane and the right for the main content) then a footer.

since i need the site to always have this layout i decided to put it in the master layout. however when i view the site, i see the default index page alright but its not in the pane as i was hoping and none of the dijit widgets gets rendered.

not sure if pasting large code in a post is allowed if not i am sorry but below is the code for the master layout. i have not done much to the default zend tool structure. i have only created a couple of modules:

```
    <?php
    Zend_Dojo::enableView($this);

    $this->dojo()->setCdnBase(Zend_Dojo::CDN_BASE_GOOGLE)
            ->addStyleSheetModule('dijit.themes.tundra')
            ->setDjConfigOption('parseOnload', TRUE)
            ->setDjConfigOption('locale', 'en-GB')
            ->setDjConfigOption('isDebug', TRUE);
    echo $this->dojo();
    ?>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.ContentPane");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.BorderContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.TabContainer");
        dojo.require("dijit.layout.AccordionContainer");
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" gutters="true" id="borderContainer">
        <div id="header" dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" region="top" splitter="false">
            <div id="logo">
                <img src="/images/logo.gif" />
            </div>

            <div id="menu">
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array(), 'home'); ?>">HOME</a>
                <a href="<?php echo $this->url(array('page' => 'services'), 'static-content'); ?>">SERVICES</a>
                <a href="#">CONTACT</a>
            </div>
        </div><!-- end header -->

        <div dojoType="dijit.layout.BorderContainer" liveSplitters="false" design="sidebar"
             region="center" id="content">
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionContainer" minSize="20" style="width: 300px;"
                 id="leftAccordion" region="leading" splitter="true">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="One fancy Pane">
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="Another one">
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="Even more fancy" selected="true">
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.AccordionPane" title="Last, but not least">
                </div> <!-- end AccordionContainer -->
            </div>
            <div dojoType="dijit.layout.TabContainer" region="center" tabStrip="true">
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My first tab" selected="true">
                    <?php echo $this->layout()->content ?>
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My second tab">
                    Lorem ipsum and all around - second...
                </div>
                <div dojoType="dijit.layout.ContentPane" title="My last tab" closable="true">
                    Lorem ipsum and all around - last...
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="footer">
            <p>Created with <a href="http://framework.zend.com/">Zend Framework</a>. Licensed under <a href="http://www.creativecommons.org/">Creative Commons</a>.</p>
        </div><!-- end footer -->
    </div>
```

Comment: Just a note, you probably don't need to nest two BorderContainers for your purposes; one with top/left/bottom/center regions ought to be enough.  Have a look at the "more advanced example" here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dijit/layout/BorderContainer.html#more-advanced-example  Also, you're missing `class="tundra"` on your body tag to actually apply the theme.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo when setting your dojo config options. Instead of

```
->setDjConfigOption('parseOnload', TRUE)
```

it needs to be

```
->setDjConfigOption('parseOnLoad', TRUE)
```

Watch the uppercase 'L'. If you fix this then at least the dojo parser will do it's job.

Didn't check if your layout is OK, see the comment of Ken.